# Redirect in codeigniter after login

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Trying to do a redirect after a successful login. The login info is sent using ajax to the controller.

My controller code as below

```
public function login_controller_function()
{
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $user_name=$this->input->post('username');
        $user_password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $result = $this->login_model->verify_user($user_name,$user_password);
        //  echo 'user_logged_in';
        if(strcmp($result,'user_logged_in')==0)
        {
            redirect('welcome');

        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working at all. Anyone knows whats wrong?

Hi my html as requested. i am using twitter bootstrap as well

```
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
<li><a href="#" id="login_btn">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('register'); ?>">Register</a></li>
```

for the buttons so when i click the login button, a modal window will appear and ask for login info.

so when i click on the login button, my js code will send an ajax request

my js code as below

```
    /*Attempt register user jquery ajax*/
    $('#login').click(function(){ 

        var user_name = $('#loginHere').find('#user_name').val();

        var user_password = $('#loginHere').find('#login_pwd').val();

        if(user_name==""||user_password=="")
            return;

        var login_data = { username:user_name, password:user_password};


                $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        url:"login_register/login_controller_function",
        data: login_data,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.login)
            {
                alert(data.redirect);
                window.location.replace(data.redirect);

            }
            else if(!data.login)
            {
                alert('data login not true');
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert('ajax error');
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are calling the controller method using ajax, you need to send back some variable or value (to indicate successful or unsuccessful login) back to the javascript which made the ajax call to handle the redirect.Or in other words the javascript should handle the redirect since you are not making the call to the controller by directly posting to the controller method, but rather via ajax.

What the ajax script will output as response to the ajax call after login and then redirecting to the welcome controller is the entire HTML of the page to which the controller method will redirect, which is not the correct way to handle the ajax call.

So I would suggest , you should rather set some session values in the controller after the login is successful and send back some value to the ajax method to indicate iof the login was successful or failure.

You can then redirect with javascript, and you should have the sessions set when you get redirected to the secure page by javascript.

Controller:

---

```
public function login_controller_function(){
$this->load->model('login_model');
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    $user_name=$this->input->post('username');
    $user_password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $result = $this->login_model->verify_user($user_name,$user_password);
    //  echo 'user_logged_in';
    if(strcmp($result,'user_logged_in')==0)
    {
     //set the session variables here so that I can access the secure area 

     //send back response to the ajax method  
     print 'success';

    }else{
        //send back response to the ajax method
        print 'failure';
    }
}
```

}

ajax script:

---

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/login_controller_function",
       data: "userName="+$('#userName').val()+"&passWord="+$('#password').val(),
       cache:false,
       success: function(msg)
           {            
            if(msg =='success'){
            //redirect to dashboard
            }
            if(msg == "failure"){
            //display login error message               
           }
     });
```

This is a basic example how the thing should work. You can of course extend it or make it more robust.

Comment: any idea how to do the redirect in the ajax? I use window.location.href when msg =='success'. It doesnt work

Comment: It should work. Can you get the error in javascript console. You should get the error in the console for the browser you are using. Do let us know which browser you are using so that we can help you to get the console message.

Comment: i am using google chrome and the developer tools as the debugger. I dont see any error in the console though.

Comment: ok. Can you put an alert inside the success if block. Instead of the two if blocks I would suggest a if elseif else block.

Comment: hi i edited the ajax as above edited. But its not working still. The alert in the success if block shows the correct url that I wanted it to be redirected to. I am using codeigniter and its routes.php. Wonder if that makes a difference?